# ControllerMacros cannot be seen in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I have a Rails app and I am trying to test it. I use devise to log in. However, I faced a problem that occurs when I want to test:

```
Users/ender/Projects/ratingw/spec/controllers/widgets_controller_spec.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `login_user' for #<Class:0x007fe909bd5070> (NameError)
```

First, I want to say that I read [this devise formal tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29).

My spec_helper.rb is:

```
  # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
    ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
    require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
    require 'rspec/rails'
    require 'rspec/autorun'
    require 'capybara/rspec'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

  OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter] = {
      :provider => 'twitter',
      :uid => '123545'
      # etc.
  }

  OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter] = :invalid_credentials

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller

  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller

  config.include RequestMacros, :type => :request

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

end

module ::RSpec::Core
  class ExampleGroup
    include Capybara::DSL
    include Capybara::RSpecMatchers
  end
end
```

and also I have a controller_macros.rb, which is located in support file:

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = Factory(:user)
      #user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the confirmable module
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

and finally, my controller_spec file is:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe WidgetsController do
  login_user

  describe "User" do
    before(:each) do
      @current_user = mock_model(User, :id => 1)
      @widget = mock_model(Widget, :user_id => 1)
      Widget.stub!(:current_user).and_return(@current_user)
      Widget.stub!(:widgets).and_return(@widget)
    end

    it "should have a current_user" do
      subject.current_user.should_not be_nil
      redirect_to widgets_path
    end

    it "should not have a current_user" do
      redirect_to widgets_path new_user_session_path
    end
  end

  def mock_widget(stubs={})
    @mock_widget ||= mock_model(Widget, stubs).as_null_object
  end

  describe "Get index" do
    it "should get all widgets " do
      Widget.stub(:all) { [mock_widget] }
      get :index
      assigns(:widgets) == @widgets
    end
  end

  describe "Post widget" do
    it "creates a new widget" do
      Widget.stub(:new).with({'these' => 'params'}) { mock_widget(:save => true) }
      post :create, :widget => {'these' => 'params'}
      assigns(:widget) == @widgets
      response.should redirect_to (edit_widget_path(@mock_widget))
    end

    it "can not create a new widget" do
      Widget.stub(:new).with({'these' => 'params'}) { mock_widget(:save => false) }
      post :create, :widget => {'these' => 'params'}
      assigns(:widget) == @widgets
      redirect_to new_widget_path
    end
  end

  describe "Get widget" do
    it "shows exact widget via its uuid" do
      Widget.stub(:find).with("10") { mock_widget(:save => true) }
      get :show
      assigns(:widget) == @widget
    end
  end

  describe "Put widget" do
    it "updates the widget attributes" do
      Widget.stub(:find_by_uuid).with("6").and_return(mock_widget(:update_attributes => true))
      mock_widget.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({'these' => 'params'})
      put :update, :uuid => "6", :widget => {'these' => 'params'}
      response.should redirect_to (edit_widget_path(@mock_widget))
    end

    it "can not update the widget attributes" do
      Widget.stub(:find_by_uuid).with("6").and_return(mock_widget(:update_attributes => false))
      mock_widget.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({'these' => 'params'})
      put :update, :uuid => "6", :widget => {'these' => 'params'}
    end
  end

  describe "delete destroy" do
    it "destroys the requested widget" do
      Widget.stub(:find_by_uuid).with("10").and_return(mock_widget)
      mock_widget.should_receive(:destroy)
      get :destroy, :uuid => "10"
    end
  end
end
```

How can I fix this? What is the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess the error stems from:

```
config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
```

You should have:

```
config.include ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
```