# RSpec controller macro not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Rails 3.2, RSpec 2.11.  Controller macro isn't working, and it appears to be written correctly from all the research I've done.  Here's the code

/spec/support/controller_macros.rb

```
module ControllerMacros
   def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      @current_user = user
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

/spec/spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ....
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

/spec/controllers/companies_controller_spec.rb

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe CompaniesController, "index companies" do
    context "for authenticated users" do
        login_user
        ...
    end
end
```

execution results:
    undefined local variable or method 'login_user' for # (NameError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12334380/979091) , you need to change your `extend` to an `include`

Comment: What if you remove the before(:each) from your macro and place the login_user within a before(:each) block within your spec?

Comment: also your describe block looks a little weird, does it work if you remove the `, " index companies"`?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the spec type fixed it for me:

Before:

```
describe Api::FooController do
   .
   .
end
```

After:

```
describe Api::FooController, type: :controller do
   .
   .
end
```

Comment: This should be the true answer. Inlining the code is never the answer.