# ControllerMacros method not being loaded by RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I've added a `ControllerMacro` but the method isn't being made available in my specs. My specs will fail with:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes_with_foreign_keys' for FactoryGirl:Module
```

I'm trying to do this following [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/359#issuecomment-24607922) discussion on Github. I've looked at [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800710/controllermacros-cannot-be-seen-in-rspec) similar questions but most point at using `config.include ControllerMacros, :type => :controller` instead of `config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller` which I'm doing already.

Now I know that the `controller_macros.rb` file is being loaded upon starting the test as I've run the specs through RubyMine's debugger but why the method isn't available is beyond me!

`spec_helper.rb`

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'email_spec'
require 'rspec/autorun'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include(EmailSpec::Helpers)
  config.include(EmailSpec::Matchers)
  config.include ControllerMacros, :type => :controller

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.order = "random"

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

`spec/support/macros/controller_macros.rb`

```
module ControllerMacros
  def attributes_with_foreign_keys(*args)
    FactoryGirl.build(*args).attributes.delete_if do |k, v|
      ["id", "type", "created_at", "updated_at"].member?(k)
    end
  end
end
```

This example controller spec:

```
describe "POST create" do
  describe "with valid params" do
    it "creates a new Course" do
      expect {
        #post :create, course: FactoryGirl.build(:course)
        post :create, course: FactoryGirl.attributes_with_foreign_keys(:course)
      }.to change(Course, :count).by(1)
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling:

`post :create, course: FactoryGirl.attributes_with_foreign_keys(:course)`

Just call:

`post :create, course: attributes_with_foreign_keys(:course)`

Took advice from @Billy Chan answer.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Thanks for posting this. I also added a comment to the Github thread where we got the code from. To help others.

Answer (score 1):

#### The reason of failing:

The macro you defined is a method within a module. You asked Rspec to include the module, so the method is available to Rspec's instance, which should be used similar to `describe`, `it` etc.

However, you used this method as a FactoryGirl's class method. Obviously this is not working.

#### The solution.

It looks you want to have a convenient method to quickly build a set of pre-defined attributes of a model in a special case.

This logic is better not to be a "macro", because it's better to use FactoryGirl as a centralized place to store all logic about models.

So, the most convenient way is, beyond your normal factories, define a special factory for this case, say `foo`, with all association and other logic you need inside it, and inherit from other normal factory.

If it's name is `foo`, then you can easily build a hash of foo's attributes like `FactoryGirl.attributes_for :foo`

Comment: Hi @Billy Chan, the association logic is already in the Factory but .attributes_for does not honour associations defined in the Factory. See this post -> https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/359#issuecomment-24607922

Comment: @FrancisOuellet, I checked the link. It looks you used the solution provided by BigNerdRanchDan. The method he wrote should be used directly in Rspec same as `describe`, `it`, but not as a method of FactoryGirl as what in your question. Change that and you should be fine with it.