# rspec controller testing with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, factory-bot

I'm using devise + rspec + factory + shoulda and having trouble with my controller specs. I've read a bunch of articles and docs but couldn't figure out what the best way is to `log_in` the user and use that user instance.

Task is nested under user so index route is `/users/:user_id/tasks` and task `belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User"` and `belongs_to :executor, class_name: "User"`

At the moment with following code both tests fail. What is the best approach for properly sign_in the user and use it in the controller tests?

The error message for the first one:

```
Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:tasks)).to eq([assigned_task, executed_task])

expected: [#<Task id: 1, assigner_id: 1, executor_id: 2, .....>, #<Task id: 2, assigner_id: 3, executor_id: 1, ......>]
        got: nil

(compared using ==)
```

The error for the second one:

```
Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to respond_with :ok }
   Expected response to be a 200, but was 302
```

tasks_controller_spec.rb

```
require "rails_helper"

describe TasksController do

  describe "when user is signed in" do

    describe "collections" do

      login_user
      let(:assigned_task) { create(:task, assigner: @user) }
      let(:executed_task) { create(:task, executor: @user) }
      let(:other_task) { create(:task) }

      context "GET index" do
        before do
          get :index, user_id: @user.id
        end

        it "assigns user's tasks" do
          expect(assigns(:tasks)).to eq([assigned_task, executed_task])
        end

        it { is_expected.to respond_with :ok }

      end

      context "GET incoming_tasks"
    end
  end 
end
```

controller_macros.rb

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      @user = create(:user)
      sign_in @user
    end
  end
end
```

tasks controller

```
def index
  @tasks = Task.alltasks(current_user).uncompleted.includes(:executor, :assigner).order("deadline DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: Task.pagination_per_page)
end
```

Comment: please provide code for index action, also please encode `login_user`  to before(;each/:all) block.

Comment: Updated with index action. Isn't the login_user already in before block?

Comment: I havent seen that `loginuser` is executed inside the before block of describe

Comment: well  you  can use `pry` gem to debug app.... introduce it to action, and to spec code and look into the context

Comment: I checked @user and it is available in the `it` block, still code fails. The `@user.current_sign_in_at = nil` though. Does that matter?

Comment: The `executed_task` and `assigned_task` are properly assigned to the `@user` if I check the instance ids in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in rails_helper.

```
config.include ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
```

[SEE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800710/controllermacros-cannot-be-seen-in-rspec) this thread.

I am assuming this only fails in rspec. When you test in browser it works fine.

Comment: Shishir, I had it with extend, changed it to include and now getting `login_user` only can be used in `it` or `before` block. As I see it's already in a `before` block. What do I miss?